# Dummies tutorial for Websocket in tomcat8 server and client

Tags: websocket, sample, tomcat8

My first post.

I have experience of basic java servlet and jsp and have got my webpage implemented in tomcat7.

Regarding Websocket, I am finding difficult to build understanding of how to implement it, i want to use tomcat8 implementation of websocket api and uplift my webpage (jsp, java, jquery, tomcat7) to use the websocket features, have not been able to find the the tutorial that can guide me through, something like hello world example. any pointers (sample codes, tutorials)?

have tried to understand tomcat8 examples but not understanding them at all

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that you don't just "add" WebSocket to an existing web application.. to make it faster, better, cheaper, more scalable, etc. Instead, you have to completely re-architect the web-layer of the application to take advantage of its capabilities.

I suggest that you first read a lot about WebSocket and what the whole idea is before you try to write any code, using Tomcat or any other WebSocket-capable server.

Nick Williams has a [forthcoming book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118656466) that appears to cover everything in the web application world, and as I understand it, will have a great deal of information about WebSocket-based code. You will unfortunately have to wait until March 2013 (at least) to use that particular book.

I'm sure there are similar books available, or even online tutorials to help get you started using WebSocket. Just be aware that switching to WebSocket isn't some simple configuration option: it's a very disruptive change to any existing web application.